# Making an image or text fixed on the page horazontally in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi on my webpage i would like to make an image and some text fixed horizontally so that when the browser change size it will move slightly untill then stop and stay still instead of currently when the browser changes my image on the left pushes all the way to the right, how will i make it stay still

Thankyou for your help

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html,body {
background-image:url(../img/background.png);
background-size:cover;
}
@font-face{
font-family:helvlight;
src:url(../img/fonts/webfontkit-20140127-181820/aliquam-webfont.ttf);
}
@font-face {
font-family:helvitalic;
src:url(../img/fonts/webfontkit-20140127-183102/aliquamulti-webfont.ttf);
}
#bar {  
margin-top:55px;
min-width:1000px center;
max-width:1920px;
height: 30px;
background: #2E2E2E;
border: 3.2px groove #FFD700;
min-width:1000px;
}
#logo { 
position:absolute;
background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
top:0px;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
#middle
{
height:10000px;
}

#social  {
top:18px;
left:200px;
height:32px;
width:500px;
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
}

.facebook {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.facebook:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_active.png);
}
.twitter {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/twitter_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.twitter:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/twitter_active.png);
}
.in {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/in_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.in:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/in_active.png);
}
.youtube {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/youtube_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.youtube:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/youtube_active.png);
}
.google {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/google_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.google:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/google_active.png);
}
.buzz {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/buzz_yahoo_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.buzz:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/buzz_yahoo_active.png);
}

#macbook {
background-image: url(../img/Untitled-2.png);
background-size: 650px;
width: 650px;
height: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
top: 18px;
left:2.5%;
}

#middleright {
font-family: helvlight;
font-size: 70px;
color: #000;
position:absolute;
left: 55%;
top: 130px;
width: 412px;
height: 164px;
z-index: 6;
min-width:40%
}
#middlerighttwo {
font-family: helvitalic;
font-size: 25px;
color: #000;
position: absolute;
left: 101.3%;
top: 200px;
width: 412px;
height: 164px;
z-index: 7;
}
#middlerightthree {
font-family: helvitalic;
font-size: 25px;
color: #000;
position: absolute;
left: 101.3%;
top: 300px;
width: 412px;
height: 164px;
z-index: 7;
}
#register {
background-image:url(../img/register-now-button-gold.png);
height:30px;
width:120px;
background-size:cover;
position:absolute;
z-index:8;
top:300px;
left:142%;
}
#register:hover {
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gold;
}

#home {
font-family:helvlight;
position:absolute;
top:47px;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFF;
left:10%;
}
#history {
font-family:helvlight;
position:absolute;
top:47px;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFF;
left:40%;
}
#society {
font-family:helvlight;
position:absolute;
top:47px;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFF;
left:68%;
}
#map {
font-family:helvlight;
position:absolute;
top:47px;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFF;
left:110%;
}
#gallery {
font-family:helvlight;
position:absolute;
top:47px;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFF;
left:137%;
}
#contactbutt {
font-family:helvlight;
position:absolute;
top:47px;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFF;
left:165%;
width:100pz;

}
#contactbutt:hover{
color:gold;
}
#home:hover{
color:gold;
}
#history:hover{
color:gold;
}
#map:hover{
color:gold;
}
#society:hover{
color:gold;
}
#gallery:hover{
color:gold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is `margin: 0 10%;` or `margin: 0 auto;`:

**CSS:**

```
.titanfall {
    background-image: url('http://cdn3-www.craveonline.com/assets/uploads/2013/06/titanfall.jpg');
    width: 658px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="titanfall">
    <h1>Titanfall</h1>
</div>
```

[Play on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nL3dK/)

---

*Edit based on OP's question modification.*

So, you want to fix `#middleright`, right? Ok, it's complicated for me positioning myself about your problem without a preview or a better know-how of the scenario. By the way, let me explain some technical issues about your div (?):

1. You're not getting centered because your div is 55% on the left of something. **The conclusion is:** you're positioning your div in 55% for the left within a wrapper with some width, that may be the window size or another div with a superior width.
2. You need to shape your div in a way that its fits the right percentage of the its wrapper's layer. I'll bet a guess: **remove** your `left: 55%` and add `margin: 0 10%;`.

Comment: Whilst it's good that you're providing an answer, but it's probably better to wait until the poster has posted their `HTML/CSS` to show that they have made an effort. ;-)

Comment: Yea, Nick R, I know. But according my interpretation of the problem, he just need to fix an image in the middle of the screen regardless of the window resizing, then I provided him a sweet solution. By the way, I'm waiting his positioning about the problem, because everybody are right: the question itself is difficult to understand.